# Parse.com Getting Array values

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

So, I don't have much experience with Parse. But, I've been reading through the documentation and it's giving me some guidance, but I still can't figure out how to get data from an Array data field.

I have an Array data field called 'Collection' and it looks something like this:

> ["170 grams tomato puree","118 milliliters water","74 milliliters
>   olive oil","2 cloves garlic","1/2 tablespoon dried oregano","1/2
>   teaspoon dried basil","1/2 teaspoon dried rosemary","salt","freshly
>   grounded pepper"]

I also have a RecipeId field which looks something like this:

> JE9sVV84Lk

Of which references to a unique field in a Recipe table. The Ingredients table all has unique fields. There is no way in which a piece of data will be entered which is a replica. This is done through validation. So at the very most, and at the very least, only one item will ever be returned because It will never be able to find another Object which is mapped against the same RecipeId. It just won't ever happen.

The code looks like this:

```
protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
ingredients = new ArrayList<>();

try {
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>("Ingredients");
   query.whereEqualTo("RecipeId", "JE9sVV84Lk");

   parseList = query.find();
   for(ParseObject object : parseList) {
    List<String> ing = object.getList("Container");
    for(String s : ing) {
    Ingredient temp = new Ingredient();
    temp.setIngredientData(s);

    ingredients.add(temp);
  }
}
```

}
}

If anybody can help, I would be greatly appreciable. Thanks.